# Not getting print from HP Thermal Printer

Tags: android, android-studio, printing, thermal-printer

```
POSPrinter posPrinter = new POSPrinter();

try {

    posPrinter.open("HPValuePrinter");
    posPrinter.claim(1000);

    posPrinter.setPowerNotify(JPOS_PN_ENABLED);

    posPrinter.setDeviceEnabled(true);

    posPrinter.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, "Hello Test\n\n\n" );

    posPrinter.cutPaper(100);

    posPrinter.setDeviceEnabled(false);
    // posPrinter.setPowerNotify(JPOS_PN_DISABLED);
    posPrinter.release();
    posPrinter.close();

} catch (Exception e ){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Integrating printer but it is not printing anything or not giving any error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please try inserting some API that transfers execution authority to others, such as sleep for about 2 to 5 seconds between cutPaper(100) and setDeviceEnabled(false). The COM port may have been closed before the print and paper cut commands were sent to the printer.